# How to bypass function parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, function

I am looking for ways to bypass function parameters. Assume i have a function:

```
void getDataFromDB(int? ID, string name) {....}
```

I would like to know the ways bypassing ID or name, smt like this:

```
entity.getDataFromDB(42);
```

or

```
entity.getDataFromDB("Customer");
```

I won't call function like this:

```
entity.getDataFromDB(null,"Customer");
```

I know i can use default values also i can use params for the last parameter.
Any good ideas?

Comment: Do you have control over the methods?  You can make parameters optional but if you cant modify the source you have to pass _something_

Comment: Why *I won't call function like this:*? It sounds like this function has more than a single responsibility.. If you can change the method it will be helpful if you share the code of that method

Comment: you can use named arguments with optionals,

Comment: Sounds like simple overloads of the method should be just what you want. Assuming you have control over the method source.

Answer (score 2):

C# has two ways to reduce function parameters:

default values (works only if no "standard" parameter follows):

```
void getDataFromDB(int? ID, string name = "Default") {....}
```

Method overloads:

```
void getDataFromDB(int? ID, string name) {....} 
void getDataFromDB(string name) => getDataFromDB(null, name); // overload using lambda
```

Answer (score 0):

combine named and optional might help.

```
void getDataFromDB(int? ID = null, string name = null) {....}
```

allows

```
getDataFromDB(ID:42);
getDataFromDB(name:"eric");
```

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, you are looking to get data either by `name` or `id` (and not both). If that is the case, then these are two distinct operations in my mind which can be solved by method overloading like this:

```
void getDataFromDB(int id) { … }

void getDataFromDB(string name) { … }
```

If there is common code between the above two methods then you can keep the common code separate and call from each method.

Personally, I would avoid `nullable`parameters as we then need to put additional `null` checks in our method. It open doors for potential bugs.